# How to upgrade iPhone 5 graphics to iPad Retina?

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display, iphone-5

I have an iPhone 5 optimized app and I would like to upgrade its graphics for iPad Retina.

How can this be accomplished?

Do I have to double the size of every graphic element I currently have from image@2x to image@4x?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is already optimised for the iPhone 5 Retina screen (as in having `@2x`) image files which are double size graphics for your image assets then you shouldn't need to do anything else for the iPad Retina Screen apart from creating iPad Retina Splash Screens (if necessary).

Comment: Having @2x graphics, whether for iPhone 5 or earlier retina iPhone displays does not mean there is nothing to consider for an iPad retina display.  The iPad display is much larger than an iPhone.  Also, the aspect ratio of the iPhone 5 is different from that of the iPad.  These all need to be considered when defining the graphics requirements.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could use iPad specific images within the app itself (using `imagename~ipad@2x.png`) but it seems you can (since iOS 4.0). Thanks for the insight!